# Qubit in a mix sin/cosine state

Tags: quantum-gate, pauli-gates

The question is pretty simple. How can I get an input qubit $|0⟩$ in the state, say $$\cos{\frac{\pi}{10}}|0⟩ + \sin{\frac{\pi}{10}}|1⟩$$ Or any other sine/cosine mix state? Which gates do I need to use?

Thanks!

Comment: What gates do you have available?

Answer (score 2):

$$R_y(\theta) = e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}Y} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\frac{\theta}{2} & -\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \\ \sin\frac{\theta}{2} & \cos\frac{\theta}{2} \end{bmatrix}$$

This gate might be named slightly differently depending on the source; [Wikipedia doesn't seem to know it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate) but [this primer on rotations on Bloch sphere](http://www.vcpc.univie.ac.at/~ian/hotlist/qc/talks/bloch-sphere-rotations.pdf) lists all rotation gates nicely.

Comment: Just to add, on IBM Q the gate $R_y$ is implemented, you can also use $U3$ gate with parameters $\phi = \lambda = 0$ giving y-rotation.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mariia and Martin. It means a lot!